# Collapsing toolbar doesn't work when content is a dynamically loaded fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an activity which makes use of a collapsing toolbar. The layout looks something like this (unrelevant stuff omitted):

```
<DrawerLayout ...>
    <FrameLayout>
        <CoordinatorLayout>
            <AppBarLayout>
                <CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" ...>
                    <Toolbar
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" .../>
                </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </AppBarLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
        </CoordinatorLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</DrawerLayout>
```

In the activity's `onCreate()`, I create a fragment and replace the `fragment_container` with it:

```
TabHostFragment f = new TabHostFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, f)
    .commit();
```

The `TabHostFragment`s layout is only a `ViewPager`, which gets populated with multiple fragments. Some of these fragments contain a recycler view. Now, when I scroll these recycler views up and down, the toolbar doesn't react at all. How do I make the toolbar disappear when scrolling down, and re-appear when scrolling up?

Comment: Have you tried adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to RecyclerView?

Comment: try this link https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii I have, but to no avail.

Comment: @manabreak have you found any solution ?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @manabreak, Got the solution? Please share

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your layout scheme accordingly.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout />

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            ...
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_with_your_viewPager" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```